# Most efficient way to save and later send output from many child processes

Tags: linux, glibc

I want to do the following on linux:

1. Spawn a child process, run it to completion, save it's stdout
2. and then later write that saved stdout to a file.

The issue is that I want to do step 1 a few thousand times with different processes in a thread pool before doing step 2.
What's the most efficient way of doing this?

The normal way of doing this would be to have a pipe that the child process writes to, and then call sendfile() to send it to the output file (saving the copy to/from userspace). But this won't work for a few reasons. First of all, it would require me to have thousands of fds open at a time, which isn't supported in all linux configurations. Secondly, it would cause the child processes to block when their pipes fill up, and I want them to run to completion.

I considered using memfd_create to create to stdout fd for the child process. That solves the pipe filling issue, but not the fd limit one. vmsplice looked promising: I could splice from a pipe to user memory but according to the man page:

> vmsplice() really supports true splicing only from user memory to a
> pipe.  In the opposite direction, it actually just copies the data to
> user space.

Is there a way of doing this without copying to/from userspace in the parent process, and without having a high number of fds open at once?

Comment: Could you have the processes write to file before dying? Either all write to the same logfile or each write their own logfile in the same directory. If each processes logfile is called log${PID}${timeStarted}.txt they will automatically be unique names. ( You could spawn 2 at the same time and if there are thousands and it lasts a long time I don't know whether there is a risk that the OS reuse a PID, but never at the same time.)

Comment: I'd like to not depend on the filesystem at all. Not only is a dependency on having write access to a specific location undesirable, but Since the goal is efficiency, making a file for each process is relatively expensive compared to moving data between buffers.

Comment: " I want to do step 1 a few thousand times with different processes in a thread pool before doing step 2" -- note that _safely_ forking multithreaded processes is nearly impossible -- you are likely to hit various bugs and deadlocks. And without ability to do that, your question becomes moot.

Comment: I thought it was safe to fork and exec right after, even in a multithreaded environment. If the code between the fork and exec doesn't touch any locks, is there any risk? I have it working now with memfd and it seems to work fine (though it has the copy to/from userspace that I wanted to avoid).